# Why am getting this error? expected initializer before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the error stated in the title error when attempting to compile. What am i doing wrong? I am trying implement a template class HashTable< K, V >::prime_below( unsigned long n). But the compiler refuses to allow me.

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


static const unsigned int max_prime = 1301081;

static const unsigned int default_capacity = 11;

namespace cop4530
{
    template <typename K, typename V>
    class HashTable
    {
    public:
        HashTable();
        HashTable( size_t size = 101 );
        ~HashTable();

        bool contains( const K & k );

        bool match( const std::pair<K, V> &kv) const;


        bool insert( const std::pair<K, V> &kv );

        bool insert( std::pair<K, V> && kv );

        bool remove( const K & k );

        void clear();

        bool load( const char *filename );

        void dump();

        bool write_to_file( const char* filename );

    private:
        void makeEmpty();

        void rehash();

        unsigned long prime_below( unsigned long n);
        void setPrimes( std::vector<unsigned long> & vprimes);


    };

#include "HashTable.hpp"

}

#endif
```

Below is the hpp file. This is how my instructor requires us to implement the header file.

```
    template <typename K, typename V>
HashTable<K,V>::HashTable(size_t )
{

}

template <typename K, typename V>
unsigned long HashTable<K,V>::prime_below (unsigned long n)
{
  if (n > max_prime)
    {
      std::cerr << "** input too large for prime_below()\n";
      return 0;
    }
  if (n == max_prime)
    {
      return max_prime;
    }
  if (n <= 1)
    {
    std::cerr << "** input too small \n";
      return 0;
    }

  // now: 2 <= n < max_prime
  std::vector <unsigned long> v (n+1);
  setPrimes(v);
  while (n > 2)
    {
      if (v[n] == 1)
  return n;
      --n;
    }

  return 2;
}

//Sets all prime number indexes to 1. Called by method prime_below(n) 
template <typename K, typename V>
void HashTable<K, V>::setPrimes(std::vector<unsigned long>& vprimes)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  vprimes[0] = 0;
  vprimes[1] = 0;
  int n = vprimes.capacity();

  for (i = 2; i < n; ++i)
    vprimes[i] = 1;

  for( i = 2; i*i < n; ++i)
    {
      if (vprimes[i] == 1)
        for(j = i + i ; j < n; j += i)
          vprimes[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the Main file Below

```
#include "HashTable.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cop4530;

int main()
{
    HashTable<int, string> t(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling commands and results

1) g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.h - Compiles Fine

2) g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.hpp -

```
HashTable.hpp:6:1: error: ‘HashTable’ does not name a type
 HashTable<K,V>::HashTable(size_t )
 ^
HashTable.hpp:12:24: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 unsigned long HashTable<K,V>::prime_below (unsigned long n)
                        ^
HashTable.hpp:44:15: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void HashTable<K, V>::setPrimes(std::vector<unsigned long>& vprimes)
```

3) g++ -std=c++ -Wall -pedantic main.cpp

```
/tmp/ccMVi6jr.o: I

n function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `cop4530::HashTable<int, std::string>::HashTable(unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `cop4530::HashTable<int, std::string>::~HashTable()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why do you `#include "HashTable.hpp"` in the header? Do you include it in the `.cpp`?

Comment: It is a requirement made by my professor. The hpp file is an extension of the .h file. I guess you can say it replaces the .cpp file. I'm still not 100% sure why he requires us to do it this way, I've even read that it is bad practice, but this is what he ask of this assignment.

Comment: You just have to love those kind of professors...

Comment: `.hxx` or `.inl` are more common extensions for this case.

Comment: I also do it that way but outside of the namespace, so that I can #Include at the top of that file without issues. I do it to clean up my interface for documentation and reference purposes since template code must be available through the definition. An alternative to inline function implementations would be to add it at the bottom of the header (as what the include does)

Comment: The code compiles just fine: http://cpp.sh/3ypk Please provide a [mcve]. By the way, you have a default constructor and a constructor with a single parameter that has a default value. It will not be possible to use the default constructor because they're ambiguous.

Comment: This code compile for me. Which compiler do you use ?

Comment: The header file is named "HashTable.h" in the HashTable.hpp file I do not include anything since it is included at the end of HashTable.h file. So, it shouldn't be including itself recursively.

Comment: I'm compiling on the school server using "g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall HashTable.hpp." I know you shouldn't compile header files, but I like to make sure everything compiles before moving forward

Comment: @user5607673 Well you can't compile the `hpp` file alone, it requires the `HASHTABLE_H` file to make any sense; how should the compiler know what a `HashTable` is in the hpp file? Just include the `HASHTABLE_H`-header in a `cpp` file and compile that.

Comment: I have updated the question to show specifically what is going on. Thanks for all input by the way. Very much appreciated.

Comment: "`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.h` - Compiles Fine"  - so you do not have a problem. HashTable.h includes HashTable.hpp so you know that both are compiling.  The attempt `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.hpp` is a mistake that obviously won't work and is not a desirable goal anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just wrong:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.hpp
```

These are the errors you get:

```
HashTable.hpp:6:1: error: ‘HashTable’ does not name a type
 HashTable<K,V>::HashTable(size_t )
 ^
HashTable.hpp:12:24: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 unsigned long HashTable<K,V>::prime_below (unsigned long n)
                    ^
```

That error should be quite clear. `HashTable` does not name a type. It doesn't name a type because it's not declared. It's not declared because the declaration is in HashTable.h. All the other errors are also related to the fact that `HashTable` isn't defined.

HashTable.hpp depends on the definitions in HashTable.h and is not useful by it self. It's just a header file and it makes no sense to try to compile it.

This is also pointless:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic HashTable.h
```

Because that is also a header.

This is correct (except for the typo in the `-std` argument):

```
g++ -std=c++ -Wall -pedantic main.cpp
```

But like your linker tells you:

```
n function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `cop4530::HashTable<int, std::string>::HashTable(unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `cop4530::HashTable<int, std::string>::~HashTable()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You haven't defined all of the member functions of the class template.

Comment: What you said makes perfect sense. Not sure what im missing. I commented out everything in the .h file except the my constructor and destructor, in order to make sure the class template is defined and tested it in the main. But I cant figure out why HashTable doesn't name a type. I've used the scope resolution in order to define in it in the .hpp file. I've used the template <typename K, typename V>. Now its saying "HashTable was not defined in this scope." I know its a simple fix, its fustrating I haven't pointed it out by now.

Comment: @user5607673 The .h file is the one that defines the template. If you comment everything but the constructor and destructor, then you don't have the definition of the template itself anymore. HashTable doesn't name a type in the .hpp file only if it's not included in the .h file, which defines HashTable. The code in the question seems mostly correct in terms of definitions, except that the definition of the destructor doesn't exist.